GS1 128 Variable Length Optional Data and FNC1 usage
I cannot find something clear about the usage of FNC1 where a variable length data is optional.
Let see, as an example, the AI 8008 as defined in the GS1 General Specification document:
AI => 8008 Date and time of production (N4+N8[+N..4])
Data Content => N8[+N..4]

The last part [+N..4] is optional and, as such, it can be empty but FNC1 must be used anyway?
If it is the last part of the barcode okay, otherwise the absence of FNC1 (even if the data is not used) may cause interpretation errors.
Ex:
8088231231090807**FNC1**
80882312310908**FNC1**

But if the last 4 character is not used?
808823123109
or
808823123109FNC1
?

I recommend you to use the GS1 Application Identifiers (GS1 AIs) website: https://ref.gs1.org/ai/ It contains data attributes about all GS1 AIs. One of the attributes is called "FNC1 required?" and it clearly states if you have to use FNC1 after entering given GS1 AI.
But there is one exception. In the documment GS1 General Specifications https://www.gs1.org/standards/barcodes-epcrfid-id-keys/gs1-general-specifications it is stated that if a variable length GS1 AI data is located at the end of data string (the last GS1 AI), then FNC1 can be omitted.
Logically, it makes sense. The FNC1 character is used to terminate variable-length strings to avoid mixing their data with the data string after it. If it is the last data item, there is no need to terminate it - there is no risk of mixing.
Lets have these data:
(01)08580000000009 (GTIN)    
(8008)241007 (Date and time of production)    
(10)55 (Batch/Lot) (variable length, max length = 20)

Now, we will create strings from these data to encode in barcodes without FNC1.
#1:
010858000000000980082410071055

The decoding result of #1 data string would be:
(01)08580000000009    
(8008)2410071055 

#2: (swapped order)
010858000000000910558008241007

The decoding result of #2 data string would be:
(01)08580000000009 
(10)558008241007

Without terminating variable length GS1 AI, it is assumed that the AI continues on. This means that all following characters are assigned to a given variable length GS1 AI up to its maximum length. (And that can be sort of exploited)
Lets change the value of (8008) from 241007 to 2410071520. Now we have these data:
(01)08580000000009 (GTIN)    
(8008)2410071520 (Date and time of production)    
(10)55 (Batch/Lot)

#3:
0108580000000009800824100715201055

The decoding result of #3 data string would be:
(01)08580000000009   
(8008)2410071520  
(10)55

#4 (watch out!)
0108580000000009105580082410071520

The decoding result of #4 data string would be:
(01)08580000000009 
(10)5580082410071520 

To sum it up. Always put variable length strings at the end. If they are the last data string, you do not have to terminate them. If there are multiple variable length strings, it is better to terminate all of them (*except the last one)(**except those that are full length)(***be very careful when implementing these exceptions, it is better (and easier) to include FNC1 even when it is not needed than to have a misinterpreted string.
